# Is it possible to run a Mac/Linux/Windows command-line app on a web server?

Tags: terminal, command-line, apple-id, appletv, webserver

Not sure if this is achievable, but here is the deal: I have a Vendor ID from our company and that information is used to retrieve an Apple Identification number, after some assets are uploaded to Itunes Connect, in order to sell it under AppleTV streaming services.

However, getting the ID is a repetitive task that takes a lot of time because we have to log in, clic several buttons, search for the feature, etc. So a figured it is possible to get that number using a command-line tool from Apple, the [Transporter](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdAbeb95d60).

It is available for Mac, Windows and Linux.

So when I search for the Vendor ID (marked in red),
[image]

using this command line:

`/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m status -u mateus@sofadigital.com -p mdtj-icmm-nxem-xqjd -vendor_id THECAPTAINALAU_SOFA_20210722_3683`

(the credentials are temporary, so you can use it at will)

I get this result:
[image]

Problem solved. However, since not everyone from my company is bright enough to install and use command line tools, I was wondering if it is possible to run it under my web server, like this:

[image]

I know it is a long shot, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate what running “on a web server” means practically? Are you looking to port apple developer tools to run on a non macOS? I’m guessing you’re looking for help writing a web app which might work better on stack overflow. We could help with a “grep|awk” to process the command line tool for Mac, but building a SPWA might be out of scope here…

Comment: @bmike you are probably right. I am not a web developer so don't know exactly how to achieve this port. I was wondering if there is a tool to run macOS (or linux, or windows) command line apps under a php engine or something like that. I guess it's more complicated. Thanks anyway, I will try asking at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Making apps is hard (months to years of effort to get all the skills), I would make a shell script or AppleScript to parse the command line tools if someone was paying me to make this for them. If you’re saving a hundred people 5 minutes 30 times a day, the budget for this will be different than if 5 people do this a few times a week.

Comment: @bmike yes, I was thinking about writing a simple app at Script Editor, problem is some people use windows, therefore my idea to focus on a web solution. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No harm leaving it up for a few months

Comment: If you know PHP (or can learn it, or Perl or something like that) and have an actual webserver already in your network, it's not hard to do something like that at all.  I'm old-school, so I'd write this in Perl CGI, it's about an hour to do something like that once you know how to use Perl CGI.  The Transporter tool runs on all 3 OS'es, so you could use ANY webserver, even IIS on Windows.

Comment: @jimtut I believe that is my case, I now a litlle about PHP and I have a WWW cluster of my own. All I need is to retrieving that ID number, and maybe if it is possible foreward it to a single email.

Comment: I know I am being greedy, but keep checking the status in looping would be freaking cool. :D

Comment: Start small. I’ve been doing this a while, and it’s still how I start a new app. Learn enough PHP to print Hello World on your webpage. That will be easy. Then, learn enough HTML and PHP to create a “form” with that text input box you want. Then, learn the PHP needed to know how to read the form input (usually called “posting” the form), and then just print back to the screen what the user (you) entered in the box. Once you can read user input, then you can do a “system call” to run Transporter, and print the output on the page (instead of just printing what they entered).

Comment: @jimtut I can do that! I know how to build a form, forward it to a php page using POST, grab the varibles and print it out. My problem is exactly the system call, wich is something I have never done.  I bumped into this 'shell_exec(string $command)' line which looks very promising. I am just concernet about compatibility, not sure if the "shell" will run a vanilla mac app just like that. Thanks for the tip tho, that's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: And, as always, something went wrong: Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in storage/ssd5/392/14021392/public_html/appleidentifier/procurar.php on line 10

Comment: @MateusRibeiro , just google for that error, without that path. There are plenty of suggestions, like these here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346125/shell-exec-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @jimtut it turns out my hosting service won't allow shell programs to run. Shame. I have created a Windows app for my coworkers for now, but I will think about a universal solution, maybe mirror some screen or something on the website.